# Check if file is in a given directory (or sub-directory) in bash

Tags: bash

How can I check if a given file is in a directory, including any directories with that directory, and so on? I want to do a small sanity check in a bash script to check that the user isn't trying to alter a file outside the project directory.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use find (it searches recursively from the cwd or in the supplied directory path):

```
find $directory_path -name $file_name | wc -l
```

Example of using this as part of a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
...

directory_path=~/src/reviewboard/reviewboard
file_name=views.py

file_count=$(find $directory_path -name $file_name | wc -l)

if [[ $file_count -gt 0 ]]; then
    echo "Warning: $file_name found $file_count times in $directory_path!"
fi
...
```

Answer (score 4):

find returns nothing (i.e. null string) if the file is not found. `if [ '' ]` would evaluate to FALSE.

```
if [ $(find "$search_dir" -name "$filename") ]; then 
  echo "$filename is found in $search_dir"
else
  echo "$filename not found"
fi
```

Comment: Comparing with the empty string response is unnecessary, the status code of the find command is enough, so `if find "$search_dir" -name "$filename"; then ...` is enough.

Answer (score 1):

`find /path/to/dir -name "filename" | wc -l` would give you number of times the file exists within `/path/to/dir` and its subdirs. Any result greater than 0 would indicate the file is within the correct path. Any result equal to 0 would mean the file is not within the path or doesn't exist.